# Database file is not copied in documents directory

Tags: iphone, sqlite

When I run my application , I cant perform DB operations. When I check documents directory of iphone simulator it doesn't contain db file. Here is my code

```
-(id)init
{
    [super init];

    databaseName=@"DSMDatabase.sqlite";

    NSArray * documentsPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString * documentDir=[documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    databasePath=[documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    return self;
}

-(void)checkAndCopyDB
{
    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager * fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(success) return;

    NSString * databasepathfromapp=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasepathfromapp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

    [fileManager release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `-init` you're assigning an autoreleased value to `databasePath`. Depending on how `-checkAndCopyDB` is called, there's an excellent chance that `databasePath` has already been deallocated and that the variable is now pointing to something completely different.

You could deal with this by retaining `databasePath` in `init` but really there's no reason to keep this in a separate method. I'd move the `databasePath`-related code in `init` down into `checkAndCopyDB`, which would work just as well and avoid autorelease issues.

Comment: So you mean to say I have to shift all code from init to checkAndCopy method , so that there will be issue of retaining databasePath. Is it? Anyway Thanks

Comment: All of the code except for the call to [super init] and the "return self" could be moved into checkAndCopyDB. Then there wouldn't be any memory concerns-- in that method. If you are using "databasePath" anywhere else outside of this method, you might still need to retain it.